# Is there a tool to determine what minimum OS my deployment target should be?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios

I've read several of the posts on stack overflow already about this topic, but none of them seem to have real answers.

**Here is my question:**

The Apple documentation clearly shows what OS is required for each method, so why isn't there a tool to let me know if I'm using any methods that require an OS later than my deployment target?

If there is such a tool I'd like to know.

I'm currently building an App that I think will run fine on iOS 3.2, but I want to make sure. It seems to work fine in the 3.2 iPad simulator, but like I said, I want to make sure.

I don't want to go through each method one by one, and I don't want to set the deployment target to anything >= 4.0 because of how many people with 3Gs phones haven't upgraded to 4.0.

BTW:
I'm running XCode 4.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no tool that does exactly what I'm asking. If anyone else discovers something, please let me know. It seems like it would be fairly easy for Apple to implement something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Generally one sets this to the oldest firmware version one has tested on, if you aren't entirely sure about what APIs you're using.

Protip: Get an old device if you want to test on old versions. Set your deployment target **ALWAYS** to the oldest firmware version you've **tested** on.

Comment: So what you're saying is you know of no such tool?

Comment: @Philip, because you can use weak linking to support framework not available on earlier iOS you will have test yourself.

Comment: Black Frog, you're missing the point of my question. All I'm wanting is a tool to confirm whether or not I'm using any methods in my code that require an OS later than 3.2. I'm not looking for a full-proof way to find out if my app will definitely not crash ever on that operating system.

Comment: The best hope you'll have is the clang static analyzer, which currently doesn't do any kind of testing like this. So no.